# how i can make url in magento which do not end with .html

Tags: php, magento

i have created two website now i want one of them all url of web site do not end with .html how i can do it.please help me.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread in the official Magento Forums:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2244/

Since your questions so far have all been about Magento, I can just once more suggest to register with the Magento Community. You will likely get much better answers there. They also have multi-language boards, so you can phrase your questions in your native language.

Answer (score 0):

you can change configuretion to set which suffix include url and you can change to exclude it too.

System->configuration->catalog->search engine optimization